# google +1 and prototype.js 1.6 "Uncaught TypeError: Function.prototype.apply: Arguments list has wrong type"

Tags: prototypejs, google-plus

The google +1 button and prototype.js 1.6 library seems to have conflicts see http://jsfiddle.net/9EF9N/

```
<div class="g-plusone" data-annotation="inline" data-width="300"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
</script>
```

If you switch to prototype 1.7 everything works as expected. 
I can't update the prototype library because it is in a complex application based on Magento 1.5.

Is there someone having the same problem and maybe could give me a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems googel have changed something. It is now working again.